# Each form element <label>+<input> on new line without <div>

Tags: html, css, forms

Is there a solution to move each form element on a new line without closing these elements on divs?

I mean:

```
<label for="one">One:</label>  <input type="text" id="one">
<label for="two">Two:</label>  <select id="two">
                                  <option value="a">a</option>
                                  <option value="b">b</option>
                               </select>
...
```

To display:

```
One:   [.......]
Two:   [a    \/]
and so on...
```

If I put on CSS:

```
input, select, label {
   display:block;
}
```

then labels are not on the same line as the form fields.

Is the only solution:

```
<div><label for="one">One:</label>  <input type="text" id="one"></div>
...
```

Comment: Why not put a `<br>` after the form elements?

Comment: This would not be the "correct" way to work with CSS-style

Comment: I think wrapping with div gives you more flexibility when styling your forms and it's common practice..

Comment: So you mean starting a new line or block without additional markup?

Comment: Without changing the mark-up you can (i) float left everything and clear left the labels; or (ii) float and clear left the labels and make the controls display block; or (iii) inject a new line character with label:before; or (iv) inject a block level box with label:before; or (v) absolute position everything.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it is like this

```
<label><span>One:</span><input type="text" id="one"></label>
```

and the css

```
label {
display:block;
position:relative;
padding-left:120px; /* adjust if necessary */
}
label > span {
position:absolute;
left:0;
}
```

Comment: This `padding-left:120px;` helped me! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Why would you use `display:block;` if you want your elements to behave `inline`? Taken directly from w3schools.com, "block: displays an element as a block element like `<p>`".

We all know that when you use `<p>` the next element is automatically placed on a new line. So if you want your `<label>` and `<input>` elements to be side by side, you must use `display:inline` or `inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
<label for="one">One:</label>  <input type="text" id="one"> <br>
```

Thats it. enjoy

Edit: expanding on what Hardy said, wrapping them in a div or span will give you more
flixibility later down the line but if your only concern is to get it all in one line, just put it like i wrote above.